# Problema con login django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, djangorestframework

Estoy realizando una api con django rest framework en la cual utilizo autenticación por token. Mi problema es que cuando obtengo los parámetros "username" y "password" de un POST request, no puedo identificar a mi usuario (creado previamente)
este es mi código:

models.py:

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    es_tecnico = models.BooleanField(name = 'es_tecnico', default = False)
```

views.py:

```
class Registrar(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = UsuarioSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #  Creando un nuevo usuario
        username = request.POST.get('user.username')
        password = request.POST.get('user.password')
        # es_tecnico = request.POST.get('es_tecnico')
        es_tecnico = False
        print(username)

        user = User.objects.create_user(username, password)
        user.save()

        token = Token.objects.create(user=user)

        usuario = Usuario.objects.create(user = user, es_tecnico = es_tecnico)
        usuario.save()

        return Response({'detail': 'El usuario fue creado con el token: ' + token.key})


class LoginView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data["user"]
        django_login(request, user)
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({"token": token.key}, status=200)
```

serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',
                  'password')

class UsuarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        fields = ('user',
                  'id',
                  'es_tecnico')

class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()
    def validate(self, data):
        username = data.get("username", "")
        password = data.get("password", "")
        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                if user.is_active:
                    data["user"] = user
                else:
                    msg = "Usuario desactivado"
                    raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
            else:
                msg = "Imposible loguear con los parametros dados"
                raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
        else:
            msg = "Se necesita el username y password"
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
        return data
```

No se si al estar trabajando con el User de django, necesito aclarar en el modelo que solamente quiero usar los campos username y password (leí que el campo email puede ser el problema)

Recibo la excepción "Imposible loguear con los parámetros dados" en LoginSerializer, por lo que deduzco que ni siquiera puede comprobar la existencia del usuario:

```
if user:
                if user.is_active:
                    data["user"] = user
                else:
                    msg = "Usuario desactivado"
                    raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
            else:
                msg = "Imposible loguear con los parametros dados"
                raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
```

tengo todas las configuarciones necesarias en settings.py, guiándome de la documentación de django rest framework, pero por si necesitan el código, es el siguiente:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = (esto no lo muestro pero está)

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'pedidos',
    'django_filters',
    'rest_framework.authtoken'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'misitio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'misitio.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

# REST_FRAMEWORK = {
#     'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES' : ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',)
# }
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',),

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Me guié por este tutorial: https://wsvincent.com/django-rest-framework-authentication-tutorial/

rest_auth ya implementa todas las vistas de login, registro, logout, etc. automáticamente

mis pasos fueron:
instalar django-rest-auth
    pip3 install django-rest-auth

agregar rest_framework.authtoken y 'rest_auth' en INSTALLED_APPS

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django_filters',
    'rest_auth',
    'corsheaders',
    'pedidos',
]
```

y en las url de mi app (llamada pedidos) agregué el path de rest-auth:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
]
```

Entonces al entrar a http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/, ya tengo implementado el login. También crea más rutas como el logout pero no las necesito, pero en ese caso la url sería:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/logout/